# Should I close/delete a question that cannot be answered?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, unanswered-questions, self-delete

Over a year ago, I posted this question in DB:

[Issues with MySQL installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112629/issues-with-mysql-installation)

I updated a couple of times since, with new information that I deemed relevant.

During the weekend, my computer died, and after a fresh reinstall of everything to factory conditions, the question is effectively unanswerable. I do not have the same problems, and I do not wish to undertake the same steps in order to replicate my issue with my same machine and try to solve it.

Given that it was voted up, there is an answer (which I did not accept), and was starred a couple of times, I think it could be useful for someone. Even though it cannot possibly be answered anymore.

Comment: You should add an answer with details about what happened.  The issues may have entirely been related to your computer problems, so sharing that information would be helpful to those with similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

No!

In its current state, it seems to be a very well-made question that will not only help you (or not...) but other people who might have the same question! Even weirder to me is that you actually found the answer to your problem which is a fresh reinstall (I'm not an expert so I might be wrong). If that really is the answer, answer your own question with the steps on how you solved your problem.

In reality, it's not that your question cannot be answered but that *the answers can't be applied to your problem because the problem is gone*. So, to keep this short, don't delete since this may help other people who have the same problem as you and if you have found a solution to your problem (maybe the fresh reinstall counts as one), post your own solution under your own question.